# Why Java has so many editions unlike C#?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, javafx

I have decided to learn another language and am in the picking phase.

Currently looking into Java and C#, but leaning towards Java because it is cross-platform. I will be mostly building web based apps, but the variety of Java editions scares me. Java EE, SE, ME, FX, what are they differences?  Are there any advantages of using one to another?

Okay, FX is for desktops, ME for mobile, SE and EE are the same, but one is for "business" the other is not. So, if I learn SE for example, what would it take to switch to EE? Or FX? My problem is that I can't really understand why SE, EE and FX are separate products? They both run same JVM, and both can do the same resulting apps. Why they are separated then?

Comment: Also note that Oracle plans to integrate Java FX into Java SE for version 9, if they get the community approval: http://openjdk.java.net/projects/openjfx/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not so devastating.

- Java SE is the standard for normal applications.
- Java ME is for mobile telephones, a subset without floating point for instance.
- Java EE is an addition for Java SE for web applications and web servers.
- Java FX is a flash player alternative, but now with java bindings/integration.

Hence Java SE forms the basics. Java EE is for web applications.

In future java will get a modular system, and the distinction will be just on library level.

Comment: But, can we say, that Java editions are built on top of same common base, and editions are just sort of additional libraries/frameworks to that base that are aimed for certain industry areas?

Comment: Java FX is a product with its own scripting, but integrates in Java SE. Java ME is a stripped version, intended for low-level mobiles with non-X86 CPUs. But yes, Java EE and Java FX are additions.

Comment: @JoopEggen: Note that Oracle dropped Java FX script in favor of a pure Java API.

Comment: Also note that EE is not only for web applications but also for other kind of server side applications.

Answer (score 16):

Think of them a *bit* like this:

- ME ~= Compact framework
- SE ~= .NET client profile
- EE ~= full .NET framework (and some extra bits :)
- FX ~= Silverlight

It's not an exact comparison, but it's a close enough start...

Answer (score 4):

When you say editor, i think you mean IDE(Integrated Development Environment).
The reason why Java has so many editors and C# doesn't, is because Java is opensource, while C# is not. So the only real good IDE you are going to find out there for C# is called "visual studio"(It is not free)

I would highly recommend you to go for java, because almost all of the tools are free to use, and even the application servers where you deploy your apps.

Don't be affraid of the java editions, if you would like to build web apps, you will need to go for JavaEE(Enterprise Edition).
Anyway this is what each of them does:

SE(Standard Edition): It contains the most basic libraries, often used in desktop apps, but it is part of the Enterprise Edition too.

EE(Enterprise Edition): Used for enterprise apps(not just web apps), so that means distributed programming, from web apps, desktop to web services...

ME(Micro Edition): Is meant for mobile technologies, not just phones, also vending machines, smart tvs, missile guidance... ;)

FX: Is a rich development platform for developing powerful clients in an easy way.

Regarding to your question, the differences between EE and SE, i already answered, in other words:

EE is an extension of SE, that includes EE and allows you to program enterprise apps.
So if you want to program in EE, you need to have SE installed(Just think about it as a system requirement).

I don't really understand what do you mean by bussiness. What i can tell you is that the Enterprise Edition, has in its libraries integrated a tool for developing bussiness components, called EJB(Enterprise Java Beans).

The reason why EE, SE and FX are separet products is because a separation of concerns is needed.

Example: Maybe you create a desktop app that does not need at all to communicate via internet. Why would you have in it enterprise libraries for distributed programming?

Whit all respects, but the last question is a bit of no sense.

Comment: @Nik Bougalis :) I am not sure but is thatVisual studio Express? 
No idea, is it any good? I suppose when you choose a programming language,you also want to work with an IDE, that is popular and a big number of people already use, so you can easier find solutions when there are difficulties. I am not familiar with that IDE, but even if I were, i think I would not recommend it.

Answer (score 3):

The different versions (SE, EE, ME and FX) are all just different APIs that sit on top of the JVM (you can find full descriptions here: [Your First Cup](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/firstcup/doc/gkhoy.html)). They are not different languages so there's no new syntax to learn switching between them, just different API calls.

Personally I prefers C# for developing web apps because of it's integration with ASP.NET and the MVC frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

See the description here [Java perspective](http://www.javaperspective.com/the-technologies.html)